# dialogflow trigger fallback from web fulfilment

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am building an app using dialogflow and actions-on-google. So far it works well, but I have an issue when trying to trigger fallbacks in my web fulfilment.

This is my code to handle fallback intents:

```
const NO_INPUT_INTENT = 'actions_intent_NO_INPUT';
const DEFAULT_FALLBACK_INTENT = 'Default Fallback Intent';

app.intent(DEFAULT_FALLBACK_INTENT, handleError);
app.intent(NO_INPUT_INTENT, handleError);
app.fallback(handleError); // If no intent is specified

function handleError(conv) {
    let data = conv.data;
    let questions = data.questions;
    let answers = [];

    let state = getState(conv);

    switch (state) {
        case 'answers':
            let unansweredQuestions = questions.filter((item) => !item.active);

            if (!unansweredQuestions.length) {
                conv.close(`It doesn't look like I can help so let's stop here. Bye for now.`);
            } else {
                let question = unansweredQuestions[0];
                answers = question.answers.map((answer) => answer.text);

                conv.contexts.set(question.speechContext, 5);

                getErrorMessage(conv, {
                    first: 'Sorry, I did not get that. ' + question.speechText,
                    second:
                        `I still don't understand your response. You can try something like ` +
                        answers[0] +
                        `, ` +
                        answers[1] +
                        ` or ` +
                        answers[2] +
                        `.`,
                    third: `Please try one of the following: ` + answers.join(', ') + '.',
                    last: `It doesn't look like I can help so let's stop here. Bye for now.`
                });
            }
            break;
        case 'questions':
            answers = questions
                .filter((question) => question.speechContext && question.speechText)
                .map((question) => question.text);

            conv.contexts.set('questions', 5);

            getErrorMessage(conv, {
                first: 'Sorry, I did not get that. What is important to you?',
                second:
                    'Sorry, try saying something like ' + answers[0] + ', ' + answers[1] + ' or ' + answers[2] + '.',
                third: `Please try one of the following: ` + answers.join(', ') + '.',
                last: `It doesn't look like I can help so let's stop here. Bye for now.`
            });
            break;
        case 'scenario':
            let scenario = data.scenario;
            answers = scenario.answers.map((answer) => answer.text);

            conv.contexts.set('categoryintent-followup', 2);

            getErrorMessage(conv, {
                first: `Sorry, what are you most likely to use it for?'`,
                second:
                    'Sorry, try saying something like ' + answers[0] + ', ' + answers[1] + ' or ' + answers[2] + '.',
                third: `Please try one of the following: ` + answers.join(', ') + '.',
                last: `It doesn't look like I can help so let's stop here. Bye for now.`
            });
            break;
        default:
            conv.contexts.set('category', 5);

            getErrorMessage(conv, {
                first: 'Sorry, what type of product are you looking for?',
                second: 'We can help you choose a camera, a laptop, a TV, a tablet, a smartphone or headphones.',
                third: `Sorry that isn't something we can help you find at the moment. We can help you pick a new camera, laptop, TV, tablet, smartphone or headphones.`,
                last: `It doesn't look like I can help so let's stop here. Bye for now.`
            });
            break;
    }
}

let repromptCount = 0;

function getErrorMessage(conv, text) {
    switch (repromptCount) {
        case 0:
            conv.ask(text.first);
            break;
        case 1:
            conv.ask(text.second);
            break;
        case 2:
            conv.ask(text.third);
            break;
        default:
            conv.close(text.last);
            break;
    }
    repromptCount++;
}
```

Which works great when either fallback intent is invoked via dialogflow. The problem is I have this bit of code:

```
function getQuestions(conv, params) {
    let scenario = params.scenario;
    let data = conv.data;

    let answers = data.scenario.answers.filter((answer) => {
        if (answer.text === scenario) {
            return answer;
        }
    });

    if (answers.length !== 1) {
        // TODO: trigger fallback intent
        return;
    }

    let formulas = (conv.data.formulas = answers[0].formulas);
    let categoryId = data.categoryId;

    let options = {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: apiUrl + 'questions/filter',
        body: {
            categoryId: categoryId,
            organisationId: organisation,
            formulas: formulas
        },
        json: true
    };

    return request(options)
        .then((response) => {
            data.questions = response;
            data.scenario = answers[0];

            conv.ask('What is important to you?');
            createSuggestions(conv, response, 'text');
            repromptCount = 0; // Reset our fallback reprompts
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            //conv.ask(JSON.stringify(error));
            conv.close('We encountered an error. Please report this and try again later.');
        });
}
```

Here, if you look at the line that starts `if (answers.length !== 1)`, I would like this to trigger the fallback intent.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You need to define an event in your fallback intent in dialogflow console.
Then simply invoke that event in your webhook under your condition `if (answers.length !== 1)`.

This described here https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/events-custom#webhook

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From your web fulfillment, you can't trigger any other intent. By this point, Dialogflow has matched your intent and is looking for the response for this intent. You would want to either call the `handleError` function directly or re-implement a fallback handler for your condition.